# Best way to construct a url in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Here is the code I'm currently using to test whether my website is deployed locally, on staging, or production:

```
def get_base_url(request=None):
    BASE_URL = request.META.get('HTTP_HOST') if request else settings.STATIC_SITE_URL
    if not BASE_URL.startswith('http'):
        BASE_URL = 'http://' + BASE_URL # such as "localhost:8000"
    return BASE_URL
```

And to do something like send a link for a password reset, I would do:

```
BASE_URL = get_base_url(request)
PATH = BASE_URL.rstrip('/') + reverse('logged_in')
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this? I tried a few others ways but this seems to return the most correct and consistent result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience in deploying many Django apps to production, the best approach would be to separate settings into different modules. It is also very good described in [Two Scoops of Django](https://www.twoscoopspress.com/products/two-scoops-of-django-1-11) in `Using Multiple Settings Files` chapter.

```
settings/
    base.py
    local.py
    stage.py
    production.py
```

`local`, `stage`, `production` inherit from `base`.

For example `local.py`:

```
from .base import *

DEBUG = True

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
    }
}

INSTALLED_APPS += ['debug_toolbar', ]

BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/'
```

For example `production.py`:

```
from .base import *

DEBUG = False

...

BASE_URL = 'https://example.com'
```

For example `stage.py`:

```
from .base import *

DEBUG = False

BASE_URL = 'https://stage.example.com'
```

After this you can just set `BASE_URL` for each specific environment in each settings file and access in from `settings.BASE_URL` everywhere you want.

If will make your life much easier and allow to configure you settings depending on environment very dynamically.